# How to print crystal report without blank space

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports, windows

I created one report in crystal report in c# windows application. Its invoice. So, its height will increase or decrease based on the invoice items.Its A4 size design.So,I need to print only the content area in printer using roll paper. But if i print it will eject full size of A4 paper.Its waste of paper. How to control it and print crystal report without blank space

Answer (score 0):

you have to create custom paper size and use this paper size in your report.
at the client machine should have same paper.